# Datepicker UI format error in Google Chrome

Tags: jquery-ui, google-chrome, datepicker

I have been doing some testing whilst using Jquery UI datepicker and have found that the date format doesn't work correctly with Chrome - if I type 13/10/2009 an error appears saying that it is incorrect format. What I think has happened is that the format is dd/mm/yyyy for all browsers and validation but for some reason chrome has defaulted to mm/dd/yyyy - i.e. it works fine across all other browsers but not Google Chrome.

Here's a link: https://www.carcreditassured.co.uk/apply-now-poor-rating/ (on this occassion I'm going to change the question type to three select boxes to aid usability but I would like to know an answer for future reference)

Here's my jquery code:

```
    $('.date-pick').datepicker({
showOn: 'both',
buttonText: 'Choose a date',
buttonImage: '/images/calendar.png',
buttonImageOnly: true,
dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
numberOfMonths: 1,
showButtonPanel: true
    });
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.
Best wishes
Rachel

P.S. After reading another post on this forum I tried to captialise the MM and that gives a format of (13 October 2009) which isn't what i'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it looks at the browser's *Locale* settings (for google, go to chrome://settings/language)

You'll need to set it for your picker control like so:

```
$('.date-pick').datepicker("option", $.datepicker.regional["en-GB"]);
```

having said that, your picker results in dates in dd/mm/yyyy format for me even if I set Google Chrome to use American English, albeit the week starts with Sunday, so it's still influenced unless you set control's culture as per code I've provided.

Comment: Hi thanks for your help, I still had the issue when I set the localisation as you mentioned so I narrowed it down to a validator issue instead of the datepicker plugin, once I added a custom validation method it worked.

Comment: nice! But doesn't the week start on Monday for UK?

Comment: Yeah I hear what your saying, I've implemented your solution so that the format is completely correct and I have the validation regular expression to overcome the validation issue - all in all the problem is solved. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

i have experienced the same issue and i solved it in a simple way, i think it will be helpful to all others too.

change the input field type to "text" from "date" or "datetime-local".

its the problem with chrome, it automatically converts the date format to default, date picker passes the date in the mentioned format. when we change the input type to text then browser will not interfere to our date. Helpfull ??? :-)

Comment: Thanks this helped for me , but I think for alot of people this solution may not be enough as they may want the date type