# JQuery Validator plugin Chrome date format

Tags: jquery, validation

I have a Datepicker field formatted like this:

```
$("input.date").datepicker({
    dateFormat : 'dd/mm/yy',
    onSelect : function() {
    $(this).keyup();
    }
});
```

I use JQuery validator 1.9 and everything goes fine in Mozilla. However in Chrome 22.0.1229.94 m when I pick a date whose day goes beyond `12` (max. month number) it throws an invalid date.

Eg:  **11/09/2012** works fine but  **26/10/2012** throws an invalid date. Seems that Chrome does not understand the dd/mm/yyyy format in my case, how can I solve this?

Comment: maybe you should switch to mm/dd/yyyy ?

Comment: There is the same question, with accepted answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6412046/datepicker-ui-format-error-in-google-chrome