# How to change the display format of the automatic datepicker in html5

Tags: html, google-chrome, input, datepicker

Google Chrome shows a datepicker when the <input **type=date**> is used (chrome V20+). The date shown in the field has a dd-mm-yy format. However, for this webpage I NEED the dd-mm-yyyy format.

The 4-digit year format is crucial for the user who enters data (eg it both shows 1745 and 1945 as '45', this is quite dangerous for some uses) on this page.

Is there a way to force Chrome (and other browsers) to show the format chosen by the developper of the website, instead of the locale?
Thanks,
Mike

Comment: I think Chrome 24+ never shows 2-digit years.

Comment: I managed to get it working with the dd-mm-YYYY format... but not sure how. I set something in the Locale, or the Browser knows im in UK. Its really annoying me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Datepicker UI format error in Google Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6412046/datepicker-ui-format-error-in-google-chrome)

Answer (score 6):

The HTML5 spec doesn't provide a way to work around this. Your best option would be to use jQuery/jQueryUI (which gives you more control) - http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#entry-examples

See also [Is there any way to change input type="date" format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372038/is-there-any-way-to-change-input-type-date-format)